# How to pass function in another file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that is used to change the state of a react component but I'm trying to pass the function in another file. I get the error that the function I'm trying to pass (changeView) is not defined.

This is the App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        language: "english",
        render: ''
    }
}

changeView(view, e){
    console.log(view);
    this.setState({render: view});
}

_renderSubComp(){
    switch(this.state.render){
        case 'overview': return <Overview />
        case 'reviews': return <Reviews />
    }
}

render() {
    const {render} = this.state
    return <Fragment>
        <Header language={this.state.language} />
        <Hero />
        <Navigation render={render}/>
        {this._renderSubComp()}
    </Fragment>;
}
```

}

I'm trying to pass the changeView method to the Navigation.JS component, so I can change the active link as well as render the components listed in the _renderSubComp method above.

```
 import React from "react";
 import "./navigation.css";
 import { changeView } from "../app";

 export default function Navigation() {
    return <div className="navigation">
        <a onClick={this.changeView.bind(this, 
'overview')}>Overview</a>
    <a>Reviews</a>
</div>;
}
```

How should I pass the function to another file so it's able to change the state of my component and render the component I need.

Comment: You may need a state management library/framework, please read more about [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or MobX](http://mobx.js.org/) it allows you to have a common state where many components can watch/change it

Comment: You are exactly looking for callbacks in React. Pass the event handler function as a props to Navigation and there in onClick call as this.props.changeView. Never do binding directly in render because it creates a new function every time your component renders and re renders so either you do it in constructor or use arrow function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't import a method like that. You will pass your function like any other prop to your component and you use there.

I've changed a few things. Firstly, I define `changeView` function as an arrow one, so we don't need to bind it. Secondly, I pass this function to the component as a prop. Thirdly, I used this function there like:

```
onClick={() => props.changeView('overview')}
```

As you can see it is `props.changeView` not `state.changeView`

Just go through [the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) a little bit more. You are confused about states, props and how to pass them to your components.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      language: "english",
      render: ''
    }
  }

  changeView = (view, e) => {
    console.log(view);
    this.setState({ render: view });
  }


  render() {
    const { render } = this.state
    return <div>
      <Navigation render={render} changeView={this.changeView} />
    </div>;
  }
}

const Navigation = (props) => {
  return <div className="navigation">
    <a onClick={() => props.changeView('overview')}>Overview</a>
    <a>Reviews</a>
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```